# Is there a way to bookmark a page and making it static in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, bookmarks, httrack

I would like to make some bookmarks being static in Firefox but I can't find anything to do this.

Example:

I bookmark a page and I want to have a look at it 3 months later. But what if it changes or disappears? I don't want to save the page with httrack or something, just a right click menu item (Make static/offline) or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Scrapbook add-on

Answer (score 5):

You can use `File > Save Page As` and save as '`Web page, complete`' to save a copy of the page.

Comment: Yes, but Scrapbook does this seamlessly, so I don't have to remember where I saved the pages.

Answer (score 2):

The Scrapbook add-on can do this and more, you can download it here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427

Answer (score 0):

You can save the page to disc. Most web browsers can do this and pull down the relevant images too.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted a built-in or feature solution.

Answer (score 0):

..or you could save it to a pdf file, using [pdfcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)